# How to display various XML tags in TreeView

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, treeview

```
<Parent id="parent">
    <ChildType1 id="SingleChild"/>
    <ChildType2>
        <ChildOfchild id="ChildChild1"/>
        <ChildOfChild id="ChildChild2"/>
    </ChildType2>
</Parent>
```

I want to display the above XML in a WPF TreeView in a manner that both ChildType1 and ChildType2 are display on the same "level" with the difference that ChildType2 will be expandable. I'm using XmlDataProvider with HierarchicalDataTemplates.

Edit.
I currently this is the code I'm using:

```
 <!-- Template for Child2 -->
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="child2_hdt">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@id, StringFormat={}ChildChild: {0}}"/>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>        

 <!-- Template for Child1 -> Child2 -->
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="child1_hdt"
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource child2_hdt}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@id, StringFormat={}Child1: {0}}"/>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<!-- Template for Parent-->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="parent_hdt"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource child1_hdt}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@id}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This works quite well except Under the Child1 in the treeview there's an empty space thats expandable.

[image: Current treeview]

Comment: "I'm using XmlDataProvider with HierarchicalDataTemplates". What exactly doesn't work with that approach?

Comment: In hierarchicalDataTemplates I can only provide one ItemTemplate and I have to provide a template for both ChildType1 and ChildType2

Comment: Please add all relevant details to your question. What did you try? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: added code and img.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem here is:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Insead of

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@id, StringFormat={}Child1: {0}}"/>
```